# Apostrophes via Mac not saving correctly to db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apostrophe, single-quotes

I have never come across this before and it's completely stumped me!

I am using some custom front end posting scripts in Wordpress, these work absolutely fine, everything is escaped correctly before the data is saved to the db etc, but I seem to be having an issue with the apostrophe (single quote) when entered on a Mac keyboard.

An example post using various chars is entered in the text area :

```
 a post with other chars `~":;?/[]{}-_=+!£$%^&*()'
```

And this is what is saved in the db (and then displayed on the page when called) :

```
 a post with other chars `~":;?/[]{}-_=+!£$%^&*()&#039;
```

This is how the data is being saved to the db for clarity :

```
esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
```

If I copy and paste an apostrophe from a webpage like this for example it saves just fine :

```
 Ain’t that strange!
```

But that slanted apostrophe isn't available (as standard) on the Mac keyboard, the default is the single quote '

I have never come across this issue before.

Anybody got any suggestions or workarounds as I'm at my wits end!

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it..

Instead of :

```
 esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
```

Use the built in wordpress function **sanitize_text_field** :

```
 'post_content' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['postContent']),
```